# Objective-C How to play a sound when a cell's button is tapped?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, tableview, avfoundation, avplayer

I have a button on each cell and while the button is tapped I want to play different audio file from array for each cell.

I don't know how to implement an array of sounds/audio files for my table view cells.

I have a button outlet and action on my `UITableViewCell`. But I am not sure how to initialise my `AVaudioplayer` in tableview.m specifically in:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell22";
```

Below I've inserted an image of the project I want to achieve. 
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBOu6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**check now i updated code :its playing sound**

1.create property in .h or .m file for ur AVAudioPlayer . like

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

2. declare **`<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>`** in .m file  and

`@synthesize audioPlayer;`

3.implement this code in :

**-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{**

```
 yourSoundArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sss",@"sss",@"sss",@"sss",@"sss",@"sss", nil];//dont include formate type


   NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: [yourSoundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ofType:@"mp3"];
                    NSLog(@"%@",audioPath);

                    NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];

                    NSError *audioError = [[NSError alloc] init];
                    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&audioError];
                    audioPlayer.delegate=self;

                 if (!audioError) {
                        NSLog(@"playing!");
                        audioPlayer play];
                  }
                    else {
                          NSLog(@"Error!");
                    }
```

4.

```
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"%d",playing the audio);
}
```

happy coding its working please check :

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. I am trying to assign sounds to the button of each cell through:
if ([_detailPhrases isEqualToString:@"Basics"]) {

}

Can I implement code above within such If statement and with the connection to the button?

Comment: in this no need button  just tap on cell it will play  sound. for playing sound no need to create button its effort. simply u can fallow above code it will work perfect

Comment: in this no need button  just tap on cell it will play  sound. for playing sound no need to create button its  extra work, giving tag values for the buttons and checking the conditions . simply u can fallow above code it will work perfect. u can handle response perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for help, I've added the inserted code above. Unfortunately, my sounds are not being played while tapping on the cells. Maybe I did something wrong. Could you please guide me.

Comment: NAVEEN KUMAR thank you very much ;) Now everything is working ;) I am so glad that you have helped me with it ;) I have one last question, where did get so much knowledge about AVFoundation? Because me and my friend started our objective-c studies recently, and we want to get into depth of Audio playing ;)
Thank you for help and for your recommendation )

Comment: Wc ..  i am glad to help u. can follow  just google and stackoverflow previous answers and compare with ur code u will get solutions easily. for better knowledge fallow apple Documentation. https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudioplayer .    please upvote the answer. :D

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this:

1. Import `AVFoundation.framework`
2. Place this code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

   NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your sound name" ofType:@"mp3"];

   NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

   AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
   [player play];

**Note:** Add your audio files to project and then take the names into one array. Then you can use your audio names based on `indexPath`.

If you want to play sound on button click which is in `tableViewCell` then add tag as `indexPath` to that button and add action to button like this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
button.tag = indexPath.row;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and paste the same code in button action. but use `sender.tag` instead of `indexPath.row`

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *soundName = [yourArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];

    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundName ofType:@"mp3"];

    NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil]; [player play];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. I am trying to assign sounds to the button of each cell through:
if ([_detailPhrases isEqualToString:@"Basics"]) {

}

Can I implement code above within such If statement and with the connection to the button?

Comment: What is the _detalPhrases and Basics?

Answer (score 0):

Mate You need to use two things mostly 
1st import AVFounfation.framwork
2nd Do code id "didSelectRowAtIndexPath"
for more details 
**[Xcode 6 - Press button to play sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467684/xcode-6-press-button-to-play-sound)**

Answer (score 0):

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

```
UITableViewCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"%@",selectedCell.textLabel.text);
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer101;

if ([_detailPhrases isEqualToString:@"Basics"]){


NSArray *soundArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"cellTapSound", @"Second", nil];

NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: [soundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ofType:@".mp3"];
NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
NSError *audioError = [[NSError alloc] init];
audioPlayer101 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&audioError];

if (!audioError) {
    [audioPlayer101 play];
    NSLog(@"playing!");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Error!");
}
}
```

}

Comment: what is ur issue ? and what is _detailPharses

Comment: cellTapSound,Second - are they  mp3 format audio files or not

Comment: I am working with two table view controllers :/  and I need to add sound files to the cells of the second table view from the 'Basics' cell of the first table view.The  '_detailPhrases' is used to perform segue connection between two table view controller.

Comment: for exaple u need to save soundAraray  like this NSArray *soundAraray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"cellTapSound.mp3",
                       @"Second.mp3",
                       nil];

Comment: u tryed ?.. is it playing

Comment: I've tried, but unfortunately it did not play any sound :(

Comment: For instance, I am trying to make my own app with the similar structure as this app SpeakEasy Russian https://appsto.re/gb/yJ0QA.i and dont know how to pass audio to the cells of the second table viewcontroller

Comment: i updated my answer please check it will work . please comment if u got any issues.